# how to check particular ID is present in string

Tags: sql-server

I want to check if a ID is present or not in a set of multiple ID.
Example

if id 5 is present in multiple id list like '1,2,3,4,5'

Comment: If possible, change your design. SQL has one data structure *dedicated* to storing sets of values, and you're not using it here. It's called a table.

Answer (score 1):

use   CHARINDEX to return the index of the searched value.

```
Declare @MyString varchar(50)
Set @MyString  = '1,2,3,4,5'
IF CHARINDEX('5',ContactName) > 0 
 Begin
    Print '5 Exists'
 End
Else
 Begin
    Print  '5 Does not exists'
 End
```

Comment: if i will be having @MyString  = '1,2,3,4,50' and then i will check IF CHARINDEX('5',ContactName) > 0 then also it will Print '5 Exists'

Comment: Exactly... this function does not check exact match

Comment: Yes.It will fail in that scenario.

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*) FROM table where id = '5';
```

If it returns more than 0 means it's present.

Comment: I am not having any table

Comment: @user1280492 That's your problem. It should be a table :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT column FROM table WHERE CHARINDEX(',5,',(',' + column + ',')) > 0
```

[**Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e1639/1)

Comment: Which will return true if the list is `1,2,35,4,6` which probably isn't desired.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about sql this query will work for you, if you get nothing it means searching id is not there in the list else there.

SELECT * FROM `journal_pulses` WHERE `mood_credentials` in (2,27)

Answer (score 0):

One good solution in this context could be to store the values with leading and trailing comma, as:

```
',1,2,3,4,5,'
```

So, even if you store one value, store it as:

```
',5,'
```

This will help you look for required value as:

```
SELECT column FROM table WHERE column like '%,5,%';
```

Or

```
SELECT column FROM table WHERE CHARINDEX(',5,',(',' + column + ',')) > 0
```

Also, using this solution you can uniquely identify different values, given that the string does not contain duplicate values.

So, it is easy to identify 5, 50 and 350 from:

```
',5,50,150,250,350,450,500,'
```

> I am not sure if you can change how the values can be stored. Please read this answer in light of the context of the question - as a starting point and not as a copy-paste solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried something like this

```
DECLARE @item VARCHAR(50)
SET @ExpressionToSearch = '23,12'

SET @item = '23'
SELECT COUNT(*) from dbo.Split(@ExpressionToSearch,',')
  WHERE ',' + (@ExpressionToSearch) + ',' 
    LIKE '%'+@item +'%'
```

This scenario will return output greater than 0